# Enable Grails 3.x auto-reload in IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Probably not important, but anyone having problem with the IntelliJ reload option in Grails?

Starting the application from the IntelliJ Run App sets 
`Reloading active: false`

I tried through the console (powershwell) to clean and relaunch the app. Reloading is true and set as expected.

Running IntelliJ 14.1.1/Grails 3.0.1/JDK 1.8.025

Comment: Reloads take forever- it's very important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try starting with `-Xverify:none` VM argument

Comment: @saw303 Funnily enough I was probably reading this at nearly the same time as you -- seems to be working for me! Steps for me: 
1. Click on your configurations drop down -- top right
2. Select 'Edit Configurations'
3. Add -Xverify:none to 'VM options' for both your Application and Grails app run configurations

Comment: @TolkienWASP what Grails and Intellij version do you use?

Comment: Grails: 3.3.0.RC1, Intellij: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5

Comment: @TolkienWASP do you work on Windows? How did you install Grails? SDKMAN?

Comment: OS: OSX 10.12.6.     Downloaded via: Homebrew and SDKMAN. Works fine for both.          Also works for Grails 3.2.11.

Comment: I am at a slightly different road. In that I am running the app in docker and I can see that reloading works wit Sublime/Atom but not with IntelliJ...
Also, what is this option -Xverify:none ?? trying with grails version 2.5.4 and docker 18.09.0

Answer (score 2):

I battled with this for a while, even attempting some deep-level stepping through in the debugger until I gave up...

It seems that the '-reloading' argument is simply ignored by grails if passed in via running the grail-app/init/.../Application using IntelliJ's run:
It auto-recompiles changed files but the running instance never reloads. It's something to do with the springloaded java agent not being set up when it's started using this method.

Anyway - I think there's two important facts in play:
Firstly Grails3 is very different to Grail2 and isn't really supported by IntelliJ 14, so you need to import it as a Gradle project.
Secondly, you need to use the gradle task called 'run' to start the app (either in 'Run' or 'Debug' mode) using Tasks->Application->Run then the automatic reloading works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If the Reloading Active is still set to "False" Follow the steps below:

1. Look on the Right side of the IntelliJ Window.
2. Click on the Gradle icon.
3. Click on tasks.
4. Click on application.
5. Click on run.

Optional: You can set the -Xverify:none option in the VM Options maybe VM Arguments too.

If that does not help, try upgrading from 1.8.0_25 to _40, _51 or _60.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Auto-reloading isn't working for me in Windows at all.

In Ubuntu everything works out of the box. For IntelliJ I had to add the following VM options in the "Grails:Appname" Run Configuration:

```
-noverify -javaagent:/<PATH_TO_GRAILS>/grails/3.0.9/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me:

1. Set the VM options to: `-Ddisable.auto.recompile=false -Xverify:none`
2. Add this to the build.gradle

   `...
   buildscript {
       ...
       dependencies {
          ...
          classpath 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.0.RELEASE'
          ...
       }
   }
   ...`

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good blog post about grails3 and itellij untitled Developing Grails 3 Applications With IntelliJ IDEA. It is the number 6 in a Grails QuickCast serie. In the minute number 3:20 you will find a -noverify reference.

Here is the link: https://www.ociweb.com/products/grails/grails-quickcast-6-developing-grails-3-applications-with-intellij-idea/