# Grails 5 multi module project recompile failed

Tags: intellij-idea, grails, grails-plugin

I am using Intellij IDEA 2021.3, on my multi module grails 5.1.5 project changes made in the **WebPlugin** won't recompile on save.
(Changes in **MainApp** recompiles on save, and changes appear on browser)

Project file structure:

```
Project
 -> MainApp //grails 5.1.5 - web project
 -> WebPlugin //grails 5.1.5 - web plugin
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling hot reload per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959215/enable-grails-3-x-auto-reload-in-intellij ?

Comment: I have tried hot reload, it works on mainApp not on webPlugin..

Comment: Did you set exploded to be true in the plugins' gradle.properties file ?  i.e. exploded=true.   And also make sure you refer to the plugin under grails { plugins { <here> }}  and not the regular dependencies section.

Comment: I have tried like below:

grails {
    exploded = true
    plugins {
        implementation project(':Module')
    }
}

this code worked in my old project grails 3.3.8 replacing implementation with compile, in grails 5 there's no more compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments, found the answer in documentation:
https://docs.grails.org/5.1.5/guide/single.html#plugins

To fix this issue you can follow next steps:

Step 1. Declare a project dependency on the plugin:

```
grails {
    plugins {
        implementation project(':myplugin')
    }
}
```

Step 2.Configure the plugin to enable reloading:

In the plugin directory, add or modify the gradle.properties file. A new property exploded=true needs to be set in order for the plugin to add the exploded directories to the classpath.